# Backyard shed with keyed hasp same as house key

Tags: doors, lock, security, shed

Anyone know if there's a solution for locking a backyard shed, that would let me rekey it to be the same as a normal house key.

The shed is a Tuff Shed with double wood doors like this:

Currently the shed is secured with a [basic swivel hasp like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00120JY1S), and padlock.

[image: basic swivel hasp]

I'm looking to minimize the number of keys I have and avoid having to fumble with a padlock (especially at night).

I've found keyed hasps like this one:
- [Prime Line Keyed Hasp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H5MU2E)

[image]

But it seems like the keys they use are tiny ones like on lockboxes, so I probably can't rekey it to my standard house key.

I'm also up for any other keyed/securing options I was thinking about maybe a keypad secured door lock (but that would probably require replacing the basic swinging wooden doors).

I've also seen T-Handle shed locks but again the keys seem like they're smaller than standard house keys (not sure if I could rekey it)

- [http://www.amazon.com/Shed-T-Handle-Lock-Set-Chrome/dp/B004WGBQBK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1460243639&sr=8-1&keywords=Shed+Windows+and+More](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004WGBQBK)

Comment: I disagree.  There's simple and universal wisdom here: go see a locksmith.  They do 10 of these before breakfast.   They can easily build a padlock with the same key as your house.  Even if it's a hard key like Primus.  They can do it at their premises, so you don't have to pay for a service call, but they will need to borrow a key to your house.  Cost will be very reasonable in the scope of what they do, but rather pricey compared to a Master lock in a plastic blister-pack at Big Orange.

Answer (score 5):

A locksmith can order (if necessary) and set up padlocks or locking hasps that respond to your house key, unless the house lock is using a particularly uncommon key blank. They may be a bit larger than the ones designed to be sold in bulk, and they will probably be a bit more expensive, but the price shouldn't be unreasonable.

Comment: Even if it's an uncommon key blank.  As long as a key core can be obtained which fits a padlock made to take key cores.  Those are usually common to doorknobs etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can just replace your house lock or locks with weiser smartkey units, and then buy a weiser smart keyed padlock.  i have six smartkey locks on the doors in my home, and a dozen or so padlocks.  all can be operated with a single key.  and, as a bonus, you can rekey your locks yourself in about 30 seconds.

Comment: There are other product lines from other manufacturers which offer the same flexibility... without having to replace all your locks took integrate the new ones.

Comment: could you let me know which ones specifically?  i have never found anyone else that offers the same package of self re-key capability and a padlock that matches.  i would be interested in comparing cost vs benefits

Comment: It's been a year since I looked seriously at my locksmithing wholesalers; lemme see if I can dig out a few specific examples... But there are several padlocks that can accept a standard KIK cylinder with a suitable tail, which should be adaptable for most keys.

Comment: ... I grant that most of these aren't intended for self-rekey. But I say again, comparing the cost of replacing cylinders throughout, plus the problem of some of the self-key systems being less secure than I like...

Comment: okay - thanks anyway.  yes, the self re-key is the main selling point.  keyed alike cylinders for padlocks and door locks have been available for decades, but the ability to regularly change your keys out is the main selling point for me.  with a single lock changeout running $50-$100, its well worth converting to the smart lock key system for me.  that way any straggler keys dont become a security risk - you just quickly rekey.  as to the security of the system, you'd have to prove it to me.  at the same pricepoint, i would stack the smartkey locks up against all competitors.

Comment: A single cylinder replacement, keyed, should run you more like $25 retail if you can install it yourself. Maybe less, depending on where you are. Swapping out the entre lockset certainly works, but may not be the right answer unless the existing lock is shoddy or badly worn. Frankly, if you want self-"rekey"__I__ would suggest a good quality electronic, not cheap but a lot more flexible.

Comment: your last post seems like a series of nonsensical arguments.  why would i remove the lock, drive to the store, have the pins changed, drive back and reinstall it - all when i can get someone to come do it for $50-$100?   i agree that its wasteful to replace a perfectly good lock for no reason, but the whole idea is to get one key that operates all locks.  that was the point of the entire original question.  and why would i replace a perfectly good lock with a digital one that costs even more money, doesnt give me single key operation, and wont last longer than 5 years at best?

Comment: Obtain a replacement cylinder, install it in existing lock. Not expensive or difficult in most cases. Combo, agreed, was a digression, but I really do have security concerns with the "smart key" systems and hesitate to suggest them for that reason; I wish it were otherwise. (And disagree about lock life, but that's a different conversation.)